# EF Core ChangeTracker: Sets only CreatedAt field in db

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

I am using the ChangeTracker to update the dates of all entites. In my case the field "CreatedAt" is only set in the db.
I have also run the debug mode, and both properties are set. And when I run the SaveChangesAsync the ModifiedAt is still null in the database. On a update the "Modified" field is also not set.

Can you see what I am doing wrong?

```
public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
        var entries = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.Entity is DateTimeInformation
                                                        && (e.State == EntityState.Added
                                                        || e.State == EntityState.Modified));
        foreach (var entityEntry in entries)
        {
            ((DateTimeInformation) entityEntry.Entity).ModifiedAt = DateTime.Now;

            if (entityEntry.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                ((DateTimeInformation)entityEntry.Entity).CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }

        return base.SaveChangesAsync();
  }
```

My DateTimeClass:

```
public abstract record DateTimeInformation
{
    public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ModifiedAt { get; set; }          
}
```

My Configuration

```
public class TextEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<PrePostText>
{
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<PrePostText> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(c => c.Id);
            builder.Property(c => c.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            builder.Property(ci => ci.CreatedAt).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            builder.Property(ci => ci.ModifiedAt).ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
            builder.Property(c => c.Name).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired();
            builder.Property(c => c.Type).IsRequired();
            builder.Property(c => c.Content).HasMaxLength(512).IsRequired();
        }
 }
```

Comment: `ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate()` needs [database trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#update-timestamp) in order to work. Also, why you are configuring Created/Modified properties as database generated if you fill them client side?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have found the solution on my own :)
The ValueGeneratedOnAdd you need ony when you use the e DatabaseGenerated attribute. In my case I do not use this, because I am overriding the SaveChangesAsync.